# TypeError: svg.append(...).attrs is not a function when creating charts using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bar-chart

I am trying to create racing bar charts using D3.js. I am fairly new to the library so I tried to modify [this example](https://observablehq.com/@johnburnmurdoch/bar-chart-race) to learn how the library works.

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error: `TypeError: svg.append(...).attrs is not a function.`

Here is my code:

```
<script>

tickDuration = 300;
top_n = 20;

height = 768;
width = 1366;

(function(){
  const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1366)
  .attr("height", 768);

  const margin = {
    top: 80,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 5,
    left: 0
  };

  let barPadding = (height-(margin.bottom+margin.top))/(top_n*5);

  let title = svg.append('text')
    .attrs({
      class: 'title',
      y: 24
    })
    .html('18 years of Interbrand’s Top Global Brands');
// More code but the above lines are causing the error.
```

How can I correct the above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d3.attrs` is not included in the default D3 bundle:

You need to install [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi#d3-selection-multi) to include the `.attrs` method.

> This module is not included in the default D3 bundle for parsimony’s sake: the single-value methods such as selection.attr are recommended for most users, as there is little benefit to the shorter syntax provided by these convenience method.

You can rewrite your code to:

```
let title = svg.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'title')
  .attr('y', 24)
  .html('18 years of Interbrand’s Top Global Brands');
```

Comment: How do you install the d3-selection-multi properly?

Comment: @ruthy_gg you can install it with npm or add it in a script tag: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi#installing